# Rewrite Rule in htaccess convert query string into slashes

Tags: plugins, htaccess

Please examine and correct this code:

I want the code to work such that if somebody visits `https://example.com/music/?record_year=2022`, it should be `https://example.com/music/record_year/2022` instead.

```
# To externally redirect https://domain.com/music/?record_year=2022 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /music/?record_year=([^\s&]+)&l=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ music/%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: this can't be done via HTAccess. You could redirect to the desired URL ( redirects and rewrites arent the same thing ), but you'd need PHP code to allow your theme/plugin to retrieve the record year etc from the URL with custom WP rewrite rules ( HTAccess rewrite rules and WP rewrite rules aren't the same either )

Comment: Am not sure about that, I read series of articles saying it is achievable through htaccess.

Comment: not in the way that you expect it to work, doing it properly requires rewrite rules as well as filters to make WordPress generate and use those new URLs, and if WP thinks it doesn't match the canonical URL it will redirect it to avoid SEO penalties. If you look you'll find plenty of ancient articles that say otherwise because they're very old or are flat out wrong

Comment: Okay, great. What other means would you recommend please.